# Is it okay to swear by the Quran to refute a claim made about me?

Tags: quran, oaths

Someone has asserted a wrong statement about me, which I have never done in my life. They were trying to punish me, even though I was innocent.   So I swear by Quran in front of them they knew that they were wrong. I am wanting to know that, have I done right? Will Allah punish me for it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no sin in that you have sworn on the authority of Allah to prove your innocence. [*Source*](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/647). But you should not have sworn on Quran, but on Allah Himself.

For the sake of completion, I must add that one may only swear on Allah, not anything or anyone else.

However, [IslamQA](http://islamqa.info/en/98194) gives a little elaboration on swearing on Quran as follows:

> As for swearing on the Mushaf, if what is meant is the words of Allaah contained therein, then it is an Islamically acceptable oath;
>    but if what is meant is the paper and ink, then it is an oath by something other than Allah, which is shirk
>   Hence it is **better not** to swear by the Mushaf